# SQL Server error on primary key constraint syntax and invalid object name in MS Fabric

Tags: sql, t-sql, microsoft-fabric

I'm currently working through a Microsoft Fabric tutorial on data warehousing in SQL Server data warehouse and have encountered an issue with a T-SQL query provided in the exercise.

The query is as follows:

```
 CREATE SCHEMA [Sales]
 GO
        
 IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables 
                WHERE name = 'Fact_Sales' AND SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) = 'Sales')
    CREATE TABLE Sales.Fact_Sales 
    (
        CustomerID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        ItemID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        SalesOrderNumber VARCHAR(30),
        SalesOrderLineNumber INT,
        OrderDate DATE,
        Quantity INT,
        TaxAmount FLOAT,
        UnitPrice FLOAT
    );
    
 IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables 
                WHERE name = 'Dim_Customer' AND SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) = 'Sales')
     CREATE TABLE Sales.Dim_Customer 
     (
         CustomerID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
         CustomerName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
         EmailAddress VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
     );
        
 ALTER TABLE Sales.Dim_Customer 
     ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Dim_Customer 
         PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (CustomerID) NOT ENFORCED
 GO
    
 IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables 
                WHERE name = 'Dim_Item' AND SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) = 'Sales')
     CREATE TABLE Sales.Dim_Item 
     (
         ItemID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
         ItemName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
     );
        
 ALTER TABLE Sales.Dim_Item 
     ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Dim_Item 
         PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (ItemID) NOT ENFORCED
 GO
    
 CREATE VIEW [Sales].[Staging_Sales]
 AS
     SELECT * 
     FROM [ExternalData].[dbo].[staging_sales];
 GO
```

When I paste it it returns this message:

```
Started running query at line
Statement ID: {19C4ACDE-FE84-42AF-9E6D-563D1DB9E819}
```

> Msg 24528, Level 0, State 1
> Statement ID: {892F958B-7E01-4EA5-A6FC-1B166AFA40B7}
>
> Msg 24528, Level 0, State 1
> Statement ID: {E91B31EB-5F5D-4BA8-8CCE-DA7F47076990}
>
> Msg 24528, Level 0, State 1
> Statement ID: {A8B553C5-7BDC-49A5-AA0C-B4F9C1B00EBA}
>
> Msg 24528, Level 0, State 1
> Statement ID: {A74F8718-4FB6-42B4-A9E4-6ACFB9E04EF3}
>
> Msg 24528, Level 0, State 1
> Invalid object name 'ExternalData.dbo.staging_sales'.
>
> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Code line NaN
> 9:13:09 PM
> Total execution time: 00:00:00.000

As evident here:

[image]

Three of the tables were successfully created but the view was not created. So I ran the following query:

```
-- Create Schema
CREATE SCHEMA ExternalData;

-- Create View
CREATE VIEW [Sales].[Staging_Sales] 
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM [ExternalData].[dbo].[staging_sales];
GO
```

The schema gets created but I get this error:

```
11:07:17 PM
Started running query at line 1
```

> Invalid object name 'ExternalData.dbo.staging_sales'.
>
> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Code line 498
> 11:07:17 PM
> Total execution time: 00:00:00.951

Also, all the sections the two lines that use Enforced both have this error/warning:

[image]

Here is the link to the MS tutorial/exercise:

https://microsoftlearning.github.io/mslearn-fabric/Instructions/Labs/06a-data-warehouse-load.html

Help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I've not used Fabric yet but with SQL Server three part names `[ExternalData].[dbo].[staging_sales]` then `dbo` is the Schema and `ExternalData` is a database name - maybe the name you gave the "new Lakehouse"?

Comment: In the tutorial the first thing I was asked to do was to create a Lakehouse which in the tutorial it says we could name it a name of our choice. Then I had to upload a sales.csv file to the Lakehouse. Thirdly, I had to create a data warehouse and again I was told to name it any name. Then I ran the query above that I posted here and I began receiving the errors. You can find the link at the bottom of the question.

Comment: yeah - I've seen the link but I'm not about to do the lab to test a theory. What did you name the LakeHouse? In the screenshot in the "Create a lakehouse and upload files" section the text in the "Explorer" says "ExternalData" - does it say something else for you?

Comment: The Lakehouse is called "A" and the Data Warehouse is called "Hamid2". Ah I just looked at the screenshot you mention. You are correct Martin, that is the name of the Lakehouse because mine says Hamid2. So it's as you mentioned, ExternalData is not the schema but refers to the name of the Lakehouse. Have I understood that correctly?.

Comment: I've added the screenshot to the question so you could see it for your reference.

Comment: Possibly - it was a guess from me. Does referencing `[Hamid2].[dbo].[staging_sales]` work?

Comment: It gives me the following error:

Invalid object name 'Hamid2.dbo.staging_sales'.

Comment: I realized why I got this error now. I didn't do this step "Create a table in the lakehouse". I need to create the staging_sales table. Let me do it. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: Okay so I created the table staging_sales in the lakehouse and then I run the query:  CREATE VIEW [Sales].[Staging_Sales] AS SELECT * FROM [Hamid2].[dbo].[staging_sales];
and it worked. Thanks so much for your help. Before you put it as an asnwer officially, the last part is regarding the "ENFORCED" line. Any idea why that error is appearing?. Thanks in advance.